# Creating new DT column in R gives an error

Tags: r, datatable

I have a datatable that has two columns `id` and `values`.
`values` column only has many numbers from interval of `-100:100`.
I want to create another column which would have `one` or `zeroes`(or `true` or `false`) depending on the value in `values`. I use this line of code:

```
dt$condition <-as.numeric(dt$values < 0)
```

but it gives me this error:

> 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)

What might be wrong..?

Comment: Is it working without `dt$condition` ? What is the class of `dt` ?

Comment: @Clemsang class is [1] "data.table" "data.frame", i`ll try that line without dt$condition right now

Comment: Please provide dt using `dput`

Comment: Give one second. I was checking simply if printing the thing without `dt$dondition` would give me true or false and it does

Comment: @Clemsang this is the actual dt I am working with:

Comment: `structure(list(fieldas = list("Ratų skersmuo", "Maksimalus naudotojo svoris (kg)", 
    "Galia, W", "Prekės ženklas"), neturima = list("8,5'' (21.60cm)", 
    "100", "250", "Xiaomi"), alternatyva = list("8,5'' (21.60cm)", 
    "100", "250", "Frugal"), score = list(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x02902498>)`

Comment: Working for me using your structure and creating the new column, please try the same

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a string value depending on the condition < 0.

```
df$condition <- ifelse(df$values < 0, "true", "false")
```

Comment: That is not the question

Comment: This piece of code is working for me:                                        
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), values = c(67,-12,45,34,68))

df$condition <- ifelse(df$values < 0, "true", "false")
df$contion_bis <- as.numeric(df$values < 0)

Comment: The problem is with the package DT, not creating a new column